# Why is it typically a switching regulator to 5 V with a further linear to 3.3V instead of both in parallel?

Tags: power-supply

I'm looking at some device's schematics of various purpose, and noticed one thing: if there is a need to go down from 12-24 V to 5V and 3.3V it is usually implemented as 24V -> 5V switching converter (alike LM2596) and then linear from 5V to 3.3V (alike AMS1117-3.3.)

Why is it like that? Wouldn't it be better to have 2 separate switching converters from 24V -> 5V and 24V -> 3.3V?

What are the reasons?

Comment: What was the load on 3.3 V in those examples?

Comment: MCU, screen (LCD), Optocouplers

Comment: If the load is low enough (low mA-range), a 5->3.3 V linear regulator might win in terms of losses over a 24->3.3 V switcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching regulators are noisier but have high efficiency. Linear regulators give cleaner voltage out but terrible efficiency and also generate lots of heat when the Vin/Vout gap is relatively large.

Therefore it is a common design to use a switching regulator for the big leap from 24V down to 5V, then use a linear regulator to obtain a cleaner 3.3V from 5V, in order to power RF parts of similar noise-sensitive circuits.

Comment: But wouldn't than an extra power filter do the job? Or it is too many extra parts?

Comment: @Araneus0390 For RF parts you'll probably want to use linear regulator _and_ an extra filter. As for the various TI "simple switchers" specifically, they are a noisy bunch even with the correct layout, so they can't even be remotely considered to power RF directly.

Comment: OK, understood. Than, perhaps, a side question. I also see that if there is any sort of wireless data transmission (does 3G modem count as RF application?), those are powered still via switching regulator (for 4.2 or 3.8 V) without further filter. Doesn't it make a problem there? Or there is no choice due to a power consumption during the transmission itself?

Comment: @Araneus0390 If it's some pre-made, stand-alone module, it could have regulators and filters built in (or alternatively you could be looking at some cheap crap solution). Or it can be an RFIC which you interact with directly when making the RF design yourself.